# Does training tensorflow model automatically save parameters?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I ran the [demo tensorflow MNIST model](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/get_started/os_setup.html#run-a-tensorflow-demo-model)(in models/image/mnist) by

```
python -m tensorflow.models.image.mnist.convolutional
```

Does it mean that after the model completes training, the parameters/weights are automatically stored on secondary storage? Or do we have to edit the code to include "saver" functions for parameters to be stored?

Comment: You may find a simple example at https://github.com/nlintz/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/10_save_restore_net.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No they are not automatically saved. Everything is in memory. You have to explicitly add a saver function to store your model to a secondary storage.

First you create a saver operation

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())
```

Then you want to save your model as it progresses in the train process, usually after N steps. This intermediate steps are commonly named "checkpoints".

```
  # Save the model checkpoint periodically.
  if step % 1000 == 0:
    checkpoint_path = os.path.join('.train_dir', 'model.ckpt')
    saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path)
```

Then you can restore the model from the checkpoint:

```
 saver.restore(sess, model_checkpoint_path)
```

Take a look at `tensorflow.models.image.cifar10` for a concrete example